# Make gmail in chrome the default email application for Yosemite

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail

I love my MacBook but I'm not a huge fan of Mail. Can I make GMail in Chrome the default email application for Yosemite so that when I click on email links I am sent to a new draft there?

I've done this before on other systems.

Answer (score 1):

To Set default protocol handler in your chrome browser, visit any web app or website which support protocol handlers (For ex: Gmail for mailto:, Google Calendar for webcal: ) and you’ll see Protocol handler icon <<>> on right side of your address bar, click that icon to set default handler.

http://www.ashout.com/complete-guide-to-google-chrome-handlers/

Answer (score 0):

Sort of...

If you mean "when I click on a "mailto:" link on a web page, can it go to my Gmail tab in Chrome instead of Apple's Mail.app." the answer is yes.

In Chrome go to Setting -> Advanced ->content Settings. Scroll down to handlers -> manage handlers and select Gmail from the mailto link.

A more complete tutorial for Chrome, Firefox and IE can be found [here.](http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht)

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing this, but ran into an issue where my "Manage Handlers" window was blank and I could not add anything to it.

Here is the javascript solution that works even if your Handlers window does not. I figured I would post this here, in case anyone else finds this post and has this problem.

- Make sure you are logged in to Gmail and the active window is your main Gmail page (or nothing will happen).
- Copy/paste this into the address bar: 
  javascript:navigator.registerProtocolHandler("mailto","https://mail.google.com/mail/?extsrc=mailto&url=%s","Gmail")
- Add the javascript: to the front again if needed, because when you pasted it, Chrome probably trimmed everything before and including the colon. Then hit enter.